# Python SMTP import

Tags: python, import, smtp

Has anyone had this before?  It's working with all the other scripts I've written.

```
import smtplib
```

File "/usr/lib64/python2.4/smtplib.py", line 49, in ?
    from email.base64MIME import encode as encode_base64
ImportError: No module named base64MIME

And it's not called email.py!

Answer (score 3):

Do `python -v` then `import smtplib` at the python command-line.

That should show you where it is getting `email` from.

EDIT:

Please could you post your output from the `import email` line.

Mine is:

```
import email # directory /usr/lib/python2.4/email
# /usr/lib/python2.4/email/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.4/email/__init__.py
import email # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.4/email/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.4/email/base64MIME.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.4/email/base64MIME.py
import email.base64MIME # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.4/email/base64MIME.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.4/email/Utils.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.4/email/Utils.py
import email.Utils # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.4/email/Utils.pyc
```

Comment: All coming from /usr/lib64/python2.4/

Comment: @jdborg Please do `ls -l /usr/lib64/python2.4/email`

Comment: Is there a way on here to attach?  The output is too long for this window